# Changing sql_mode does not work within PHP queries

Tags: php, mysql

If I run `SELECT @@sql_mode` I get this on queries executed within PHP:

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

If I run `SELECT @@sql_mode` directly within mysql or thru a remote connection to the server, I get this:

```
NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

If I run `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` and then `SELECT @@sql_mode` within PHP (with or without transaction encapsulation) I get this:

> ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

I've added this to my `~/.my.cnf`, `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` files and restarted MySQL but still no impact:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

I tried restarting the entire server. No change.

Where could PHP be getting this MySQL configuration from?? I have no other `my.cnf` files that I can tell. Please help

MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 in vagrant.

Comment: Which API are you using - mysqli or PDO

Comment: @NigelRen PDO within Laravel

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the Laravel `database.php` config for mysql being set to strict mode. Changing `database.connections.mysql.strict` to `false` fixed the issue.